# Jenkins+Robot Framework : Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure. Does not timeout

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, robotframework

I am trying to configure a robotframework test from jenkins. I have used shell script "`robot -d results -i 1-city-zip-login-change-city tests/simple-test-gateway.robot`"

On running the build, build does not time out even after 20 min. Have to manually abort the test. Test runs fine from pycharm.

**Below is the console output**

> - robot -d results -i 1-city-zip-login-change-city tests/simple-test-gateway.robot
>     ============================================================================== Simple-Test-Gateway :: This test covers basic features for the website
>     regr...
>     ============================================================================== Consumer and merchant able to sign in with single-city zip - chang...
>     Second signal will force exit. [ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page
>     Screenshot' could not be run on failure: Execution terminated by
>     signal Build was aborted

Comment: Presumably you are trying to open a web browser. What does the log say for `open browser`? Also, is you jenkins server running in a headless environment? Selenium tests require a display for it to open the browser on.

Comment: I am new to this. I dont see browser opening, do we have to specify in jenkins to use browser specifically? i am on mac local jenkins.  Console output does not show any steps executed.

Comment: Well, in order for a selenium test to run, it must first open a browser. That's not the job of jenkins, that's the job of your robot test. If no browser is open, taking a screenshot is impossible because there's no window to capture. I recommend creating a test that does nothing but open a browser, take a screenshot, and then exit. Get that running before trying to tackle anything bigger.

Comment: Sorry, i have step to open the browser in my robot test. i was saing about jenkin not opening any browser. But when run from pycharm i see browser opening and executing fine.                       
======================================================
Simple-Test-Gateway :: This test covers basic features for the website regr...
======================================================
Consumer and merchant able to sign in with single-city zip - chang... | PASS |

Comment: On what OS is Jenkins running? Are you running your browser in headless mode on the server or have you tried it?

Comment: I am on macOS High Sierra - 10.13.4. I think Jenkins runs the test in headless mode by default right? i may be wrong. I m not sure how to have jenkins interact with actual browser. I do not see browser opening when i run from jenkins. is this something i need to configure in jenkins?

Comment: Is Jenkins running locally on your own macOS system, the same you're developing on?

Comment: Yes, i have the jenkins on same laptop with same oS that i have my scripts developed on.

Comment: I also tried below shell script to run with absolute path-> "whereis python
cd /Users/msuresh/PycharmProjects/optimus-prime/
python -m robot.run tests/"                                                              ==============================================================================
Tests                                                                         
====================================================
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/Users/<name>/PycharmProjects/optimus-prime/tests/peapod-regression-tablet.robot': Resource file '../resources/peapod.robot' does not exist.

Comment: Can you add the code in question? And are you sure that Jenkins has the same rights (and configs) as when you run the tests manually?

Comment: Not sure how to check the setting permission of jenkin.Below is my test:
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
*** Variables ***

*** Keywords ***

Begin web test
    Open Browser  https://www.google.com  chrome
    set window size     1620  980
    
End web test
    Close All Browsers


*** Test Cases ***

Learning test case

    [Documentation]  Jenkin integration
    [Tags]  smoke
    Begin web test
    sleep   5s
    End web test